# Send EOF to named pipe - cleaning up / drying up fifo

Tags: shell-script, pipe, tail, fifo

If I have some random processes reading from a named pipe:

```
tail -f MYNAMEDPIPED 
cat MYNAMEDPIPE | someOtherProc
```

Elsewhere, I have a handle on MYNAMEDPIPED by name.
is there a safe and clean way to stop the tail process by deleting MYNAMEDPIPED or perhaps somehow "drying it up"?

In other words

```
MYNAMEDPIPED.noMoreDataIsComingThroughSoPleaseStopTailingThis()
```

:)

From one of the comments, it says to send EOF to MYNAMEDPIPE. But I cannot figure out how to do this.

This shows the difficulty I am facing:

http://comp.os.linux.questions.narkive.com/2AW9g5yn/sending-an-eof-to-a-named-pipe

Comment: Feed `EOF` into the input side of the pipe, `tail` will see it and close its end.  This should normally happen automagically when whatever had been writing to the pipe was done.  Remember to clean up after yourself and `rm` what you had `mkfifo`ed earlier.

Comment: thanks, can you show an actual example of sending EOF to a named pipe?

Comment: The whole purpose of `tail -f` is that it *ignores* any suggestion that it has reached the end of the file (or pipe); it will wait forever for someone to reopen the file and start writing to it again. Compare with something like `cat MYNAMEDPIPE`, which will block until something writes to it, but will indeed exit once the writer closes its end and all remaining data has been read.

Comment: maybe `cat <<EOF > MYNAMEDPIPED` ?

Comment: need help please with sending EOF to named pipe.

Comment: The only reasonable way to terminate `tail -f` is to send a signal to it, e.g. with `kill`.

Comment: yeah, I guess I will have to write the pid of the tail command to a file

Answer (score 14):

**`EOF` is not a character** nor an "event" and could not be sent through the pipe, or "fed" to its writing end, as some stubborn urban legend suggests.

The **only** way to generate an `EOF` on the reading end of a pipe/fifo (ie cause a `read(2)` on it to return 0) is to close all open handles to its writing end.

This will happen automatically if all the processes that had opened a named pipe in write mode and all the children that have inherited the file descriptors through `fork()` are terminated [1].

It's not possible for a `read(2)` on a named pipe to return 0 it that pipe was opened in read/write mode, eg. with

```
exec 7<>/path/to/fifo
```

because in that case there is a single file descriptor / handle for both ends of the pipe and closing the write end will also close the read end making impossible for a `read(2)` to return 0 (pipes do not support any kind of half-close as sockets do with `shutdown(2)`).

[1] And all processes that have received the file descriptor via `SCM_RIGHTS` ancillary message on a unix socket.

---

Notice that `tail -f` *by definition* won't terminate upon `EOF`, whether the file it's reading from is regular or special. One way to kill all processes that are holding a open handle to a file descriptor is with `fuser(1)`:

```
tail -f /path/to/fifo
...
> /path/to/fifo  # let any blocking open(2) through
fuser -TERM -k /path/to/fifo
```

Beware that this will also kill processes that have (inadvertently) inherited an open handle to `/path/to/fifo` from their parents.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot “send EOF”.  There is simply no “EOF character” that would go through the pipe.

Typically, linux programs read from a file descriptor using `read`(2) in blocking mode, filling a buffer with the received data, and returning the amount of characters read.  When `read` returns 0, i.e., 0 bytes have been read, most programs interpret this as end-of-file.

A program may flush its side of the pipe before the buffer is full, using `fsync`(2).  In that case, the reader's `read` would return immediately, even if the buffer is empty, returning 0 as the amount of readbytes.

You can observe this by running `cat`, typing some characters (not return) and hit Ctrl-D (which causes a flush by the terminal).  At that moment, `cat` will print the typed characters.  Hit Ctrl-D again, and `cat`'s `read` will return 0 bytes, making `cat` assume to have reached end of file.  Since line-buffering is used, `cat` also prints its input when you hit Return.

Comment: what this answer describes in the last paragraph only happens with ttys, not with pipes; a `fsync()` on the write end of the pipe will not cause a `read()` on the reading end to return 0, even if the pipe's buffer was empty.